# How do you install drivers during/prior to Lubuntu alternative installation?

Tags: drivers, system-installation, lubuntu, ubuntu-drivers

I have a Dell Vostro 1000 laptop with a broadcom wireless card. I have successfully installed Lubuntu and gotten the WLAN working in the past. I am currently trying to perform a fresh install using the alternative installer. The broadcom wlan card needs a special driver, firmware-b43-installer, that is not in he default distribution. I can download a .deb file containing the driver but it will not stall from the installer shell. The installer shell is also missing apt-get and dpkg so I can't use them. How does one add drivers to the system without using any of these methods?

EDIT: Thanks, everyone! I can use a netowrk cable to do this but I'm trying to use this as a leaning experience to better understand how the linux installation process works. The idea I've had but not yet tried is to manually copy the driver files into their appropriate locations. From the package manager on my running system I know the files are installed to the locations below. Would manually copying them to the installer file system them running modprobe work?

/.

/lib

/lib/firmware

/lib/firmware/b43

/usr

/usr/share

/usr/share/doc

/usr/share/doc/firmware-b43-installer

/usr/share/doc/firmware-b43-installer/NEWS.Debian.gz

/usr/share/doc/firmware-b43-installer/changelog.Debian.gz

/usr/share/doc/firmware-b43-installer/copyright

/usr/share/lintian

/usr/share/lintian/overrides

/usr/share/lintian/overrides/firmware-b43-installer

Comment: Do you have unzip? Find out: man unzip. If you have the manual page, you have the program. If so, I will propose a solution. Also, do you have another computer you can transfer files from?

Comment: use a fixed connection to download the DEB?

Comment: There is no unzip or gzip but there is tar. I can put any files that I need onto my usb stick prior to installation.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I have to use whenever I do a fresh install on my Dell Inspiron 1000 is to use an ether net cable to install the broadcom firmware.  Works everytime.